# How to compare dates and skip if date is passed in jinja2?

Tags: python, jinja2

I have a jinja2 for loop that loops through my database and posts events on a website. However I can't figure out how to compare the date that is on a specific event to the current date. If the date of the event is passed I want the loop to skip the event and not post it.

This is what I have for posting my events:

```
    {% for post in post.items %}
    <div class="col-auto mb-3 eventcard h-100">
        <a href="{{ url_for('event', event_id=post.id) }}">
            <div class=" text-center" style="width: 18rem;">
                <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='pictures/' + post.thumbnail) }}" class="card-img-top" alt="">
                <div class="">
                    <h5 class="card-title">{{post.title}}</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">{{post.event_date.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')}}</p>
                    <p class="btn btn-read">LÆS MERE</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

How do I compare todays date with the "{{post.event_date.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')}}" and make Jinja skip if the date is passed?

Answer (score 1):

You can use filter the list, for example:

```py
from jinja2 import Template
from datetime import datetime

template = """\
{% for post in post.items if post.event_date > now() %}
<p class="card-text">{{post.event_date.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')}}</p>
{% endfor %}
"""

j2_template = Template(template)


class post:
    items = [
        {"event_date": datetime(1970, 1, 1)},  # <-- skip
        {"event_date": datetime(2022, 1, 1)},  # <-- skip
        {"event_date": datetime(2040, 1, 1)},  # <-- ok
        {"event_date": datetime(2050, 1, 1)},  # <-- ok
    ]


print(j2_template.render(post=post, now=datetime.utcnow))
```

Prints:

```html
<p class="card-text">01-01-2040</p>

<p class="card-text">01-01-2050</p>
```

Comment: How to I change the format of date time.utc now so its comparable to the format used in the example I used.